# Magento2 Custom Multi shipping address in checkout page

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.4

I am working on magento2 checkout and I want to 1order split into multiple orders based on number of shipping addresses and other orders as child order so how can I handle it?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Magento already supports this function

Steps Configure Multiple Shipping Addresses in Magento 2:

1. Login to Magento 2 admin panel
2. Navigate to Stores > Settings > Configuration
3. Under Sales, select Multishipping Settings
4. Expand Option section
5. Set Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses to Yes/No based your requirement
6. In Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses, enter your required amount
7. Click Save Config

Now you can see that there is an option to checkout with multiple addresses on the cart page in the frontend

Comment: Yes but I need these functionality in checkout page before shipping method

Comment: On the checkout page you cannot check out with multiple addresses.